# Getting color value HEX code android

Tags: java, android, textview

Hey I am following Android Learning series from thenewboston. I am on this part : http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=QjQg8NkHGbw

Now, what I wanna do is save some basic color's like Red, Green etc somewhere (in code or in a file) and allocate them HEX code.

Like if user type "red" in 'edittext' then I want to store value of "red" as "#FF0000" (just like #define in C++) and so on for blue, green etc.

I am already familiar with file handling in C++ but this seems totally different.

I have no idea how to store the value of string which itself would be string.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add a file called color.xml in values folder in ur project add the following contents in it

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
 <color name="white">#FFFFFF</color>
 <color name="yellow">#FFFF00</color>
 <color name="fuchsia">#FF00FF</color>
 <color name="red">#FF0000</color>
 <color name="silver">#C0C0C0</color>
 <color name="gray">#808080</color>
 <color name="olive">#808000</color>
 <color name="purple">#800080</color>
 <color name="maroon">#800000</color>
 <color name="aqua">#00FFFF</color>
 <color name="lime">#00FF00</color>
 <color name="teal">#008080</color>
 <color name="green">#008000</color>
 <color name="blue">#0000FF</color>
 <color name="navy">#000080</color>
 <color name="black">#000000</color>
</resources>


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
 <color name="White">#FFFFFF</color>
 <color name="Ivory">#FFFFF0</color>
 <color name="LightYellow">#FFFFE0</color>
 <color name="Yellow">#FFFF00</color>
 <color name="Snow">#FFFAFA</color>
 <color name="FloralWhite">#FFFAF0</color>
 <color name="LemonChiffon">#FFFACD</color>
 <color name="Cornsilk">#FFF8DC</color>
 <color name="Seashell">#FFF5EE</color>
 <color name="LavenderBlush">#FFF0F5</color>
 <color name="PapayaWhip">#FFEFD5</color>
 <color name="BlanchedAlmond">#FFEBCD</color>
 <color name="MistyRose">#FFE4E1</color>
 <color name="Bisque">#FFE4C4</color>
 <color name="Moccasin">#FFE4B5</color>
 <color name="NavajoWhite">#FFDEAD</color>
 <color name="PeachPuff">#FFDAB9</color>
 <color name="Gold">#FFD700</color>
 <color name="Pink">#FFC0CB</color>
 <color name="LightPink">#FFB6C1</color>
 <color name="Orange">#FFA500</color>
 <color name="LightSalmon">#FFA07A</color>
 <color name="DarkOrange">#FF8C00</color>
 <color name="Coral">#FF7F50</color>
 <color name="HotPink">#FF69B4</color>
 <color name="Tomato">#FF6347</color>
 <color name="OrangeRed">#FF4500</color>
 <color name="DeepPink">#FF1493</color>
 <color name="Fuchsia">#FF00FF</color>
 <color name="Magenta">#FF00FF</color>
 <color name="Red">#FF0000</color>
 <color name="OldLace">#FDF5E6</color>
 <color name="LightGoldenrodYellow">#FAFAD2</color>
 <color name="Linen">#FAF0E6</color>
 <color name="AntiqueWhite">#FAEBD7</color>
 <color name="Salmon">#FA8072</color>
 <color name="GhostWhite">#F8F8FF</color>
 <color name="MintCream">#F5FFFA</color>
 <color name="WhiteSmoke">#F5F5F5</color>
 <color name="Beige">#F5F5DC</color>
 <color name="Wheat">#F5DEB3</color>
 <color name="SandyBrown">#F4A460</color>
 <color name="Azure">#F0FFFF</color>
 <color name="Honeydew">#F0FFF0</color>
 <color name="AliceBlue">#F0F8FF</color>
 <color name="Khaki">#F0E68C</color>
 <color name="LightCoral">#F08080</color>
 <color name="PaleGoldenrod">#EEE8AA</color>
 <color name="Violet">#EE82EE</color>
 <color name="DarkSalmon">#E9967A</color>
 <color name="Lavender">#E6E6FA</color>
 <color name="LightCyan">#E0FFFF</color>
 <color name="BurlyWood">#DEB887</color>
 <color name="Plum">#DDA0DD</color>
 <color name="Gainsboro">#DCDCDC</color>
 <color name="Crimson">#DC143C</color>
 <color name="PaleVioletRed">#DB7093</color>
 <color name="Goldenrod">#DAA520</color>
 <color name="Orchid">#DA70D6</color>
 <color name="Thistle">#D8BFD8</color>
 <color name="LightGrey">#D3D3D3</color>
 <color name="Tan">#D2B48C</color>
 <color name="Chocolate">#D2691E</color>
 <color name="Peru">#CD853F</color>
 <color name="IndianRed">#CD5C5C</color>
 <color name="MediumVioletRed">#C71585</color>
 <color name="Silver">#C0C0C0</color>
 <color name="DarkKhaki">#BDB76B</color>
 <color name="RosyBrown">#BC8F8F</color>
 <color name="MediumOrchid">#BA55D3</color>
 <color name="DarkGoldenrod">#B8860B</color>
 <color name="FireBrick">#B22222</color>
 <color name="PowderBlue">#B0E0E6</color>
 <color name="LightSteelBlue">#B0C4DE</color>
 <color name="PaleTurquoise">#AFEEEE</color>
 <color name="GreenYellow">#ADFF2F</color>
 <color name="LightBlue">#ADD8E6</color>
 <color name="DarkGray">#A9A9A9</color>
 <color name="Brown">#A52A2A</color>
 <color name="Sienna">#A0522D</color>
 <color name="YellowGreen">#9ACD32</color>
 <color name="DarkOrchid">#9932CC</color>
 <color name="PaleGreen">#98FB98</color>
 <color name="DarkViolet">#9400D3</color>
 <color name="MediumPurple">#9370DB</color>
 <color name="LightGreen">#90EE90</color>
 <color name="DarkSeaGreen">#8FBC8F</color>
 <color name="SaddleBrown">#8B4513</color>
 <color name="DarkMagenta">#8B008B</color>
 <color name="DarkRed">#8B0000</color>
 <color name="BlueViolet">#8A2BE2</color>
 <color name="LightSkyBlue">#87CEFA</color>
 <color name="SkyBlue">#87CEEB</color>
 <color name="Gray">#808080</color>
 <color name="Olive">#808000</color>
 <color name="Purple">#800080</color>
 <color name="Maroon">#800000</color>
 <color name="Aquamarine">#7FFFD4</color>
 <color name="Chartreuse">#7FFF00</color>
 <color name="LawnGreen">#7CFC00</color>
 <color name="MediumSlateBlue">#7B68EE</color>
 <color name="LightSlateGray">#778899</color>
 <color name="SlateGray">#708090</color>
 <color name="OliveDrab">#6B8E23</color>
 <color name="SlateBlue">#6A5ACD</color>
 <color name="DimGray">#696969</color>
 <color name="MediumAquamarine">#66CDAA</color>
 <color name="CornflowerBlue">#6495ED</color>
 <color name="CadetBlue">#5F9EA0</color>
 <color name="DarkOliveGreen">#556B2F</color>
 <color name="Indigo">#4B0082</color>
 <color name="MediumTurquoise">#48D1CC</color>
 <color name="DarkSlateBlue">#483D8B</color>
 <color name="SteelBlue">#4682B4</color>
 <color name="RoyalBlue">#4169E1</color>
 <color name="Turquoise">#40E0D0</color>
 <color name="MediumSeaGreen">#3CB371</color>
 <color name="LimeGreen">#32CD32</color>
 <color name="DarkSlateGray">#2F4F4F</color>
 <color name="SeaGreen">#2E8B57</color>
 <color name="ForestGreen">#228B22</color>
 <color name="LightSeaGreen">#20B2AA</color>
 <color name="DodgerBlue">#1E90FF</color>
 <color name="MidnightBlue">#191970</color>
 <color name="Aqua">#00FFFF</color>
 <color name="Cyan">#00FFFF</color>
 <color name="SpringGreen">#00FF7F</color>
 <color name="Lime">#00FF00</color>
 <color name="MediumSpringGreen">#00FA9A</color>
 <color name="DarkTurquoise">#00CED1</color>
 <color name="DeepSkyBlue">#00BFFF</color>
 <color name="DarkCyan">#008B8B</color>
 <color name="Teal">#008080</color>
 <color name="Green">#008000</color>
 <color name="DarkGreen">#006400</color>
 <color name="Blue">#0000FF</color>
 <color name="MediumBlue">#0000CD</color>
 <color name="DarkBlue">#00008B</color>
 <color name="Navy">#000080</color>
 <color name="Black">#000000</color>
</resources>
```

Comment: Thanks but I was wondering how to change string to int.
Example if user enter "Red" , I could do

    tvColor.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.Red));

(but I will need to use a switch and case and it would be long)

Is there a way like 

    String id = "R.color.";
    String id =  "R.id." + etUser.getText();
    tvColor.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(id));

Comment: @KartikSharma i would suggest to provide users option to select color via spinner then u dont need to write switch case u can use "R.id."++ etUser.getText();

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this: color.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
 <color name="white">#FFFFFF</color>
 <color name="yellow">#FFFF00</color>
 <color name="fuchsia">#FF00FF</color>
 <color name="red">#FF0000</color>
 <color name="silver">#C0C0C0</color>
 <color name="gray">#808080</color>
 <color name="olive">#808000</color>
 <color name="purple">#800080</color>
 <color name="maroon">#800000</color>
 <color name="aqua">#00FFFF</color>
 <color name="lime">#00FF00</color>
 <color name="teal">#008080</color>
 <color name="green">#008000</color>
 <color name="blue">#0000FF</color>
 <color name="navy">#000080</color>
 <color name="black">#000000</color>
 <color name="White">#FFFFFF</color>
 <color name="Ivory">#FFFFF0</color>
 <color name="LightYellow">#FFFFE0</color>
 <color name="Yellow">#FFFF00</color>
 <color name="Snow">#FFFAFA</color>
 <color name="FloralWhite">#FFFAF0</color>
 <color name="LemonChiffon">#FFFACD</color>
 <color name="Cornsilk">#FFF8DC</color>
 <color name="Seashell">#FFF5EE</color>
 <color name="LavenderBlush">#FFF0F5</color>
 <color name="PapayaWhip">#FFEFD5</color>
 <color name="BlanchedAlmond">#FFEBCD</color>
 <color name="MistyRose">#FFE4E1</color>
 <color name="Bisque">#FFE4C4</color>
 <color name="Moccasin">#FFE4B5</color>
 <color name="NavajoWhite">#FFDEAD</color>
 <color name="PeachPuff">#FFDAB9</color>
 <color name="Gold">#FFD700</color>
 <color name="Pink">#FFC0CB</color>
 <color name="LightPink">#FFB6C1</color>
 <color name="Orange">#FFA500</color>
 <color name="LightSalmon">#FFA07A</color>
 <color name="DarkOrange">#FF8C00</color>
 <color name="Coral">#FF7F50</color>
 <color name="HotPink">#FF69B4</color>
 <color name="Tomato">#FF6347</color>
 <color name="OrangeRed">#FF4500</color>
 <color name="DeepPink">#FF1493</color>
 <color name="Fuchsia">#FF00FF</color>
 <color name="Magenta">#FF00FF</color>
 <color name="Red">#FF0000</color>
 <color name="OldLace">#FDF5E6</color>
 <color name="LightGoldenrodYellow">#FAFAD2</color>
 <color name="Linen">#FAF0E6</color>
 <color name="AntiqueWhite">#FAEBD7</color>
 <color name="Salmon">#FA8072</color>
 <color name="GhostWhite">#F8F8FF</color>
 <color name="MintCream">#F5FFFA</color>
 <color name="WhiteSmoke">#F5F5F5</color>
 <color name="Beige">#F5F5DC</color>
 <color name="Wheat">#F5DEB3</color>
 <color name="SandyBrown">#F4A460</color>
 <color name="Azure">#F0FFFF</color>
 <color name="Honeydew">#F0FFF0</color>
 <color name="AliceBlue">#F0F8FF</color>
 <color name="Khaki">#F0E68C</color>
 <color name="LightCoral">#F08080</color>
 <color name="PaleGoldenrod">#EEE8AA</color>
 <color name="Violet">#EE82EE</color>
 <color name="DarkSalmon">#E9967A</color>
 <color name="Lavender">#E6E6FA</color>
 <color name="LightCyan">#E0FFFF</color>
 <color name="BurlyWood">#DEB887</color>
 <color name="Plum">#DDA0DD</color>
 <color name="Gainsboro">#DCDCDC</color>
 <color name="Crimson">#DC143C</color>
 <color name="PaleVioletRed">#DB7093</color>
 <color name="Goldenrod">#DAA520</color>
 <color name="Orchid">#DA70D6</color>
 <color name="Thistle">#D8BFD8</color>
 <color name="LightGrey">#D3D3D3</color>
 <color name="Tan">#D2B48C</color>
 <color name="Chocolate">#D2691E</color>
 <color name="Peru">#CD853F</color>
 <color name="IndianRed">#CD5C5C</color>
 <color name="MediumVioletRed">#C71585</color>
 <color name="Silver">#C0C0C0</color>
 <color name="DarkKhaki">#BDB76B</color>
 <color name="RosyBrown">#BC8F8F</color>
 <color name="MediumOrchid">#BA55D3</color>
 <color name="DarkGoldenrod">#B8860B</color>
 <color name="FireBrick">#B22222</color>
 <color name="PowderBlue">#B0E0E6</color>
 <color name="LightSteelBlue">#B0C4DE</color>
 <color name="PaleTurquoise">#AFEEEE</color>
 <color name="GreenYellow">#ADFF2F</color>
 <color name="LightBlue">#ADD8E6</color>
 <color name="DarkGray">#A9A9A9</color>
 <color name="Brown">#A52A2A</color>
 <color name="Sienna">#A0522D</color>
 <color name="YellowGreen">#9ACD32</color>
 <color name="DarkOrchid">#9932CC</color>
 <color name="PaleGreen">#98FB98</color>
 <color name="DarkViolet">#9400D3</color>
 <color name="MediumPurple">#9370DB</color>
 <color name="LightGreen">#90EE90</color>
 <color name="DarkSeaGreen">#8FBC8F</color>
 <color name="SaddleBrown">#8B4513</color>
 <color name="DarkMagenta">#8B008B</color>
 <color name="DarkRed">#8B0000</color>
 <color name="BlueViolet">#8A2BE2</color>
 <color name="LightSkyBlue">#87CEFA</color>
 <color name="SkyBlue">#87CEEB</color>
 <color name="Gray">#808080</color>
 <color name="Olive">#808000</color>
 <color name="Purple">#800080</color>
 <color name="Maroon">#800000</color>
 <color name="Aquamarine">#7FFFD4</color>
 <color name="Chartreuse">#7FFF00</color>
 <color name="LawnGreen">#7CFC00</color>
 <color name="MediumSlateBlue">#7B68EE</color>
 <color name="LightSlateGray">#778899</color>
 <color name="SlateGray">#708090</color>
 <color name="OliveDrab">#6B8E23</color>
 <color name="SlateBlue">#6A5ACD</color>
 <color name="DimGray">#696969</color>
 <color name="MediumAquamarine">#66CDAA</color>
 <color name="CornflowerBlue">#6495ED</color>
 <color name="CadetBlue">#5F9EA0</color>
 <color name="DarkOliveGreen">#556B2F</color>
 <color name="Indigo">#4B0082</color>
 <color name="MediumTurquoise">#48D1CC</color>
 <color name="DarkSlateBlue">#483D8B</color>
 <color name="SteelBlue">#4682B4</color>
 <color name="RoyalBlue">#4169E1</color>
 <color name="Turquoise">#40E0D0</color>
 <color name="MediumSeaGreen">#3CB371</color>
 <color name="LimeGreen">#32CD32</color>
 <color name="DarkSlateGray">#2F4F4F</color>
 <color name="SeaGreen">#2E8B57</color>
 <color name="ForestGreen">#228B22</color>
 <color name="LightSeaGreen">#20B2AA</color>
 <color name="DodgerBlue">#1E90FF</color>
 <color name="MidnightBlue">#191970</color>
 <color name="Aqua">#00FFFF</color>
 <color name="Cyan">#00FFFF</color>
 <color name="SpringGreen">#00FF7F</color>
 <color name="Lime">#00FF00</color>
 <color name="MediumSpringGreen">#00FA9A</color>
 <color name="DarkTurquoise">#00CED1</color>
 <color name="DeepSkyBlue">#00BFFF</color>
 <color name="DarkCyan">#008B8B</color>
 <color name="Teal">#008080</color>
 <color name="Green">#008000</color>
 <color name="DarkGreen">#006400</color>
 <color name="Blue">#0000FF</color>
 <color name="MediumBlue">#0000CD</color>
 <color name="DarkBlue">#00008B</color>
 <color name="Navy">#000080</color>
 <color name="Black">#000000</color>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save the value till the time app is get deleted you can use `SharedPreferences` feature of Android.

Link :
You can check the Vogella site for this "[ShareadPreferences sample code from Vogella](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidFileBasedPersistence/article.html)"
[Android developer site for shareadpreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)